# Getting data from two different tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, aggregate-functions

I have two tables, the first table is "registration" table, the second table is "messages" table, the registration table has a column for "reg_id(primary key)", and "membership(either 'participant' or 'graphics)'" while the messages table has a column for "message_id(primary key)", "reg_id(foreign key from the first table)", "receiver_reg_id", "completed(the value of this is either 0, 1 or 2)".

How can I do it so that I will have the list of all the users where membership='graphics' and reg_id(from the registration table)=receiver_reg_id and count(completed=0 or completed =1 "note: this does not include 2")<5.

This is what I've tried but it's not working(my query):

```
SELECT r.reg_id 
from registration r 
join messages m 
on (r.reg_id=m.receiver_reg_id) 
WHERE r.membership='graphics' and sum(m.completed=1 or m.completed=0)<5
```

(But it's not working.)

Sample data:

Registration Table:

```
reg_id: 1, name: Mr A, membership: graphics.
reg_id: 2, name: Mr B, membership: participant.
reg_id: 3, name: Mr C, membership: graphics.
```

Messages table:

```
message_id: 1, reg_id: 2, receiver_reg_id: 1, completed: 0.
message_id: 2, reg_id: 2, receiver_reg_id: 3, completed: 2.
message_id: 3, reg_id: 1, receiver_reg_id: 2, completed: 1.
message_id: 4, reg_id: 2, receiver_reg_id: 3, completed: 0.
message_id: 5, reg_id: 1, receiver_reg_id: 3, completed: 1.
message_id: 6, reg_id: 2, receiver_reg_id: 3, completed: 0.
message_id: 7, reg_id: 1, receiver_reg_id: 3, completed: 1.
message_id: 8, reg_id: 2, receiver_reg_id: 3, completed: 0.
message_id: 9, reg_id: 1, receiver_reg_id: 3, completed: 1.
```

Expected output:

```
reg_id :1.
```

It is only reg_id :1 that met the whole criteria.

The messages table is a conversation, the reg_id on the messages table is the reg_id of the sender while the receiver_reg_id is the reg_id of the receiver.

It shows the receiver has a membership of graphics, and the sum/count of all the "completed" that is either 1 or 0 "but not two"(for that particular receiver) is less than 5.

`reg_id:2` failed because it's membership is not graphics
`reg_id:3` failed because the sum/count of all the completed that is either 1 or 0 is upto 5.

I hope the question is clearer.

Comment: I've used it but there is still something I'm not getting right which I'm yet to know

Comment: I have edited the question to include: query, sample data and the expected output as you requested, thanks for your interest in  my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want the `SUM` you want the `count` of rows that have the value of `1` or `0` for the `completed` column. This should do it:

```
SELECT r.reg_id, count(completed) as da_count
from registration r 
join messages m 
on r.reg_id=m.receiver_reg_id
WHERE r.membership='graphics' and m.completed in (0, 1)
group by m.receiver_reg_id
having da_count < 5
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c515f0d/6

`SUM` adds the actual value of the column so your `0`s would count as nothing.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I eventually did. I included group by in what you gave me and it worked, thank you very much. "SELECT r.reg_id from registration r join messages m on p.reg_id=m.receiver_id WHERE r.membership='graphics' and completed in (0, 1) GROUP by m.receiver_reg_id HAVING COUNT(completed) < 5"

Comment: I also achieved it through another method: "SELECT reg_id from registration WHERE membership='graphics' and reg_id in (SELECT receiver_reg_id from messages WHERE completed in (0, 1) GROUP by receiver_reg_id HAVING COUNT(completed) < 5)" I will mark your comment as answer, you can just edit it to have the GROUP BY so that anyone see it again can get it perfectly

Comment: Thank you very much, you really saved me a lot of stress

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a condition on a calculation, it needs to be selected up front and referenced in a HAVING.

```
SELECT r.reg_id, 
sum(m.completed) as c
from registration r join 
messages m on 
r.reg_id=m.receiver_reg_id
WHERE r.membership='graphics' 
and (m.completed=1
or m.completed=0) GROUP BY r.reg_id
HAVING c<5
```

Comment: thanks for offering a helping hand, I tried this but it's not working.

Comment: Try now.  I edited.  If not working can you tell me the error please?

Comment: It returned an  empty result when I tried it in mysql, and that shouldn't be, I've edited my question to include, sample data and expected output where I explained my question better.